# Force $.ajax to fail silently

Tags: jquery

I'd like to catch the error that is thrown when I get a 404 so that it fails silently instead of displaying:

```
> GET {URL} 404 (Not Found)
```

There's a line in the jQuery source that leads me to believe that this can actually be caught.

```
// This may raise an exception which is actually
// handled in jQuery.ajax (so no try/catch here)
```

I've used the `error` and `statusCode` in settings with no luck.

```
var settings = {
  url        : '/api',
  statusCode : { 404: function() { console.log(404, arguments); } },
  error      : function() { console.log('error', arguments); },
  success    : function(data) { console.log('data', data); }
};
$.ajax(settings);
```

Comment: Unfortunately you can't. that isn't a javascript error.

Comment: Is there a 'recoverable' status code that I can send instead of 404?

Comment: statuscode [204](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.5) might be appropriate

Comment: Basically, anything in the 2xx range would not result in it printing to console. 204 definitely does not have the same meaning as 404, but it might make more sense than returning 200. Depends on your api i guess.